# Python list next to tuple syntax

Tags: python, list, tuples

I saw this syntax while playing a coding game of someone putting a list next to a tuple like this.

```
(1,3)[True]
```

this results in the answer

```
3
```

I couldn't find anything documenting this syntax.

Could someone explain this interaction better or direct me to a documentaion of it?

Comment: That's not a list. Have you learned about indexing yet?

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

The `True` mentioned above is for index `1` and `False` for index `0`

**Demo:**

```
tpl = (1,3)
print(tpl[True])  # True == 1 --> Returns 3
print(tpl[False]) # False == 0 --> Returns 1
```

---

```
print(int(True))  # 1
print(int(False)) # 0
```

**Note**: Not a good coding practice to use this

Comment: Isn't True any number that isn't 0?

Comment: @programmingisfun123. Yes. but in the above example, it represents `0` or `1`

Comment: I understand ty

Comment: Don't confuse converting integers to booleans with converting booleans to integers. All non-zero `int` values have a truth value of `True`, but the integer value of `True` is *exactly* `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Tuple has indexes like list or str, too. So `True == 1` and `False == 0`

```
(1,3)[True]  # 1st element of tuple
>>> 3


(1,3)[False]  # 0 element of tuple
>>> 1
```